# Xpath Select all subnodes of a group of nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

How can I select all subnodes of the current node?

```
  XmlNodeList productNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//PRODUCT");
        Parallel.ForEach(productNodes.Cast<XmlNode>(),
                         (XmlNode productNode) =>
                         {
                             string _productMode = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "@mode");
                             Product product = new Product()
                             {
                                 Mode = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "@mode"),
                                 No = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./SUPPLIER_PID"),
                                 DescriptionShort = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./PRODUCT_DETAILS/DESCRIPTION_SHORT"),
                                 DescriptionLong = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./PRODUCT_DETAILS/DESCRIPTION_LONG"),
                                 EANCode = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./PRODUCT_DETAILS/EAN"),
                                 Stock = XmlUtils.nodeAsInt(productNode, "./PRODUCT_DETAILS/STOCK"),
                                 OrderUnit = default(QuantityCodes).FromString(XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS/ORDER_UNIT")),
                                 ContentUnit = default(QuantityCodes).FromString(XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS/CONTENT_UNIT")),
                                 Currency = default(CurrencyCodes).FromString(XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS/PRODUCT_PRICE/PRICE_CURRENCY")),
                                 VAT = XmlUtils.nodeAsInt(productNode, "./PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS/PRODUCT_PRICE/TAX"),
                             };
                             XmlNodeList MimeNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(".//MIME");

                             Parallel.ForEach(MimeNodes.Cast<XmlNode>(), (XmlNode MimeNode) =>
                             {
                                 Mime mime = new Mime()
                                 {
                                     Source = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(MimeNode, "./MIME_SOURCE"),
                                     Type = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(MimeNode, "./MIME_TYPE"),
                                     Purpose = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(MimeNode, "./MIME_PURPOSE")
                                 };
                                 product.Mime.Add(mime);
                             });......
<PRODUCT mode="new">
        <SUPPLIER_PID>1902</SUPPLIER_PID>
        <PRODUCT_DETAILS>
            <DESCRIPTION_SHORT>NORDEN Table</DESCRIPTION_SHORT>
            <DESCRIPTION_LONG>massive birch wood. 135x74cm, 74 cm height by Mikael Warnhammar</DESCRIPTION_LONG>
        </PRODUCT_DETAILS>
        <PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS>
            <ORDER_UNIT>C62</ORDER_UNIT>
            <CONTENT_UNIT>C62</CONTENT_UNIT>
            <NO_CU_PER_OU>1</NO_CU_PER_OU>
        </PRODUCT_ORDER_DETAILS>
        <PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>
            <VALID_START_DATE>2013-05-28</VALID_START_DATE>
            <VALID_END_DATE>2013-05-30</VALID_END_DATE>
            <PRODUCT_PRICE price_type="nrp">
                <PRICE_AMOUNT>33.00</PRICE_AMOUNT>
                <PRICE_CURRENCY>EUR</PRICE_CURRENCY>
                <LOWER_BOUND>200</LOWER_BOUND>
                <TERRITORY>AT</TERRITORY>
            </PRODUCT_PRICE>
        </PRODUCT_PRICE_DETAILS>
        <MIME>
            <MIME_SOURCE>http://www.google.de/</MIME_SOURCE>
            <MIME_TYPE>text/html</MIME_TYPE>
            <MIME_PURPOSE>url</MIME_PURPOSE>
        </MIME>
        <MIME>
            <MIME_SOURCE>http://www.stackoverflow.com</MIME_SOURCE>
            <MIME_TYPE>text/html</MIME_TYPE>
            <MIME_PURPOSE>url</MIME_PURPOSE>
        </MIME>
    </PRODUCT>
```

actually i get all the product nodes and i am trying to get all the mimes sub nodes of each product node to save it.. but when i do i get the mime node repeated.

I dont know much about xpath maybe is because i need to speficy the ancestor node ? i tried using descendant but i am getting the same result.

Comment: It is better to use Xml Linq (XDocument) where you can use Descendants() to get all sub nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try following Xml Linq solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> productNodes = doc.Descendants("PRODUCT").ToList();

            List<Product> product = productNodes.Select(x => new Product() {
                Mode = (string)x.Attribute("mode"),
                No = (string)x.Element("SUPPLIER_PID"),
                DescriptionShort = (string)x.Descendants("DESCRIPTION_SHORT").FirstOrDefault(),
                DescriptionLong = (string)x.Descendants("DESCRIPTION_LONG").FirstOrDefault(),
                //EANCode = XmlUtils.nodeAsString(productNode, "./PRODUCT_DETAILS/EAN"),
                //Stock = XmlUtils.nodeAsInt(productNode, "./PRODUCT_DETAILS/STOCK"),
                OrderUnit = (string)x.Descendants("ORDER_UNIT").FirstOrDefault(),
                ContentUnit = (string)x.Descendants("CONTENT_UNIT").FirstOrDefault(),
                Currency =  (string)x.Descendants("PRICE_CURRENCY").FirstOrDefault(),
                mime = x.Elements("MIME").Select(y => new Mime() {
                    Source = (string)y.Element("MIME_SOURCE"),
                    Type = (string)y.Element("MIME_TYPE"),
                    Purpose = (string)y.Element("MIME_PURPOSE")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public string Mode  { get; set;}
        public string No  { get; set;}
        public string DescriptionShort  { get; set;}
        public string DescriptionLong  { get; set;}
        public string EANCode  { get; set;}
        public string OrderUnit  { get; set;}
        public string ContentUnit  { get; set;}
        public string Currency  { get; set;}
        public string Vat  { get; set;} 
        public List<Mime> mime { get; set;}
    }
    public class Mime
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set;}
        public string Purpose { get; set;}

    }
}
```

Comment: tyvm for you help.